# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs

I am using the [source code](https://github.com/FilledStacks/flutter-tutorials/tree/master/041-firestore-security-rules-with-testing/compound) from a security rules [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rx4pVS1vPGY) to attempt to do integration testing with Jest for my Javascript async function `async_create_post`, used for my firebase HTTP function `create_post` The files involved has a directory structure of the following:

Testing file: `root/tests/handlers/posts.test.js`

File to be tested: `root/functions/handlers/posts.js`

Helper code from the tutorial: `root/tests/rules/helpers.js`

And here is the source code that is involved:

**posts.test.js**

```
const { setup, teardown} = require("../rules/helpers");
const {
  async_get_all_undeleted_posts,
  async_get_post,
  async_delete_post,
  async_create_post
} = require("../../functions/handlers/posts");


describe("Post Creation", () => {
  afterEach(async () => {
    await teardown();
  });

  test("should create a post", async () => {

    const db = await setup();


    const malloryUID = "non-existent uid";
    const firstPost = {
      body: "First post from Mallory",
      author_id: malloryUID,
      images: ["url1", "url2"]
    }

    const before_post_snapshot = await db.collection("posts").get();
    expect(before_post_snapshot.docs.length).toBe(0);


    await async_create_post(firstPost); //fails at this point, expected to create a new post, but instead threw an error
    const after_post_snapshot = await db.collection("posts").get();
    expect(after_post_snapshot.docs.length).toBe(1);
  });

});
```

**posts.js**

```
const {admin, db } = require('../util/admin');
//admin.initializeApp(config); //my credentials
//const db = admin.firestore();
const { uuid } = require("uuidv4");

const {
  success_response,
  error_response
} = require("../util/validators");


exports.async_create_post = async (data, context) => {

  try {    
    const images = [];
    data.images.forEach((url) => {
      images.push({
        uid: uuid(),
        url: url
      });
    })
    const postRecord = {
      body: data.body,
      images: images,
      last_updated: admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      like_count: 0,
      comment_count: 0,
      deleted: false,
      author_id: data.author_id
    };

    const generatedToken = uuid();

    await db
      .collection("posts")
      .doc(generatedToken)
      .set(postRecord);

    // return success_response();
    return success_response(generatedToken);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in creation of post", error);
    return error_response(error);
  }
}
```

When I run the test in Webstorm IDE, with 1 terminal running `Firebase emulators:start` , I get the following error message.

```
console.log
    Error in creation of post TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Object
        at validateString (internal/validators.js:120:11)
        at Object.basename (path.js:1156:5)
        at GrpcClient.loadProto (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/google-gax/src/grpc.ts:166:23)
        at new FirestoreClient (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/v1/firestore_client.js:118:38)
        at ClientPool.clientFactory (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:330:26)
        at ClientPool.acquire (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:87:35)
        at ClientPool.run (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/pool.js:164:29)
        at Firestore.request (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js:961:33)
        at WriteBatch.commit_ (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:485:48)
        at exports.async_create_post (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/handlers/posts.js:36:5) {
      code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
    }

      at exports.async_create_post (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/functions/handlers/posts.js:44:13)


Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: 1
Received: 0
<Click to see difference>


    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/isaac/Desktop/project/tests/handlers/posts.test.js:59:45)
```

`Error in creation of post` comes from the `console.log("Error in creation of post", error);` in `posts.js`, so the error is shown in the title of this post.

> I want to know why calling the `async_create_post` from `posts.test.js` will cause this error and does not populate my database with an additional record as expected behaviour. Do inform me if more information is required to solve the problem.

Here are some code snippets that may give more context.

**helpers.js** [Copied from the repository]

```
const firebase = require("@firebase/testing");
const fs = require("fs");

module.exports.setup = async (auth, data) => {
  const projectId = `rules-spec-${Date.now()}`;

  const app = firebase.initializeTestApp({
    projectId,
    auth
  });

  const db = app.firestore();

  // Apply the test rules so we can write documents
  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId,
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore-test.rules", "utf8")
  });

  // write mock documents if any
  if (data) {
    for (const key in data) {
      const ref = db.doc(key); // This means the key should point directly to a document
      await ref.set(data[key]);
    }
  }

  // Apply the actual rules for the project
  await firebase.loadFirestoreRules({
    projectId,
    rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8")
  });

  return db;
  // return firebase;
};

module.exports.teardown = async () => {
  // Delete all apps currently running in the firebase simulated environment
  Promise.all(firebase.apps().map(app => app.delete()));
};

// Add extensions onto the expect method
expect.extend({
  async toAllow(testPromise) {
    let pass = false;
    try {
      await firebase.assertSucceeds(testPromise);
      pass = true;
    } catch (error) {
      // log error to see which rules caused the test to fail
      console.log(error);
    }

    return {
      pass,
      message: () =>
        "Expected Firebase operation to be allowed, but it was denied"
    };
  }
});

expect.extend({
  async toDeny(testPromise) {
    let pass = false;
    try {
      await firebase.assertFails(testPromise);
      pass = true;
    } catch (error) {
      // log error to see which rules caused the test to fail
      console.log(error);
    }

    return {
      pass,
      message: () =>
        "Expected Firebase operation to be denied, but it was allowed"
    };
  }
});
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');


const {
  async_get_all_undeleted_posts,
  async_get_post,
  async_delete_post,
  async_create_post
} = require('./handlers/posts');



exports.create_post = functions.https.onCall(async_create_post);
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, and it's hard to tell what's going wrong.  Could you edit this down to show the **minimal** code that reproduces the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A huge chunk of the code was copied from online tutorials, but I adopted a file structure arised from combining code from different sources. I'm not sure if the error message came from my personal implementation or some installation matters. Updated the post with more explanation.

Comment: Narrowing down the specific lines of code that cause the problem is part of the debugging process, which is require to get good help on Stack Overflow.  If you post hundreds of lines of code, the chances that someone will sort through it all for you goes way down.

Comment: U have a try catch block , just comment out from bottom to top until it does not console.log your error. But reading through your code i think data.images might be object[] but is treated as string[]

Comment: The underlying implementation of the `async_create_post` is that the data contains an `images` array of strings, for each string, we want to convert it into a map, with a `uid`, and the initial string `url`. I’m not sure why the compiler should care whether I’m passing in an array of objects or an array of strings. After all, regardless of whatever is inside the initial input `images` array, it should still create a new array as well as a post record right?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in NextJs 13.3.1 appDir. nextJs supports sharing of parent metadata to its sub-routes such as open-graph images. The error was caused when obtaining parent metadata for the `generateMetadata()` function using `ResolvingMetadata` which is not supported for version 13.3.1. It happened in a dynamic route as such: `[id]/page.tsx`.

```
import type { Metadata, ResolvingMetadata } from "next";

export async function generateMetadata(
  {
    params: { id },
  }: {
    params: { id: string };
  },
  parent: ResolvingMetadata
): Promise<Metadata> {
  // your metadata implementation here ...
}
```

I removed the parent metadata implementation to the one below and it worked fine.

```
import type { Metadata } from "next";

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { id },
}: {
  params: { id: string };
}): Promise<Metadata> {
   // your metadata implementation here ...
}
```

It works well for version 13.4.4, not so certain for any other versions before it.

Answer (score -3):

The error message means that a method of the `path` module (like `path.join`) expects one of its arguments to be a string but got something else.

I found the offending line by binary search commenting the program until the error was gone.

Maybe one of your modules uses `path` and you supply the wrong arguments.